# FParsec failing on many

Tags: f#, fparsec

I have this test program:

```
open FParsec

let test p str =
    match run p str with
    | Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "Success: %A" result
    | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" errorMsg

let str s = pstring s

let sepPart = skipNewline >>. pstring "-"

let part = manyChars (notFollowedBy sepPart >>. anyChar)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let s = "AA 12345\nBB 6789\n-----\nCC 9876\nDD 54321\n-----"
    test part s
    test (many part) s

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The line {test part s} works as expected but the next line, {test (many part) s} fails and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:

To clarify, what I am trying to do is have {test (many part) s} return ["AA 12345\nBB 6789"; "CC 9876\nDD 54321"]. In words, what I have is an input string composed of "pars" or "chunks" separated by lines with all dashes. For output I want an array where each element is one of the parts and the lines with dashes are simply discarded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you execute your example, FParsec throws an exception with the following message:

> Additional information: (Ln: 2, Col: 8): The combinator 'many' was
>   applied to a parser that succeeds without consuming input and without
>   changing the parser state in any other way. (If no exception had been
>   raised, the combinator likely would have entered an infinite loop.)

The problem is that your `part` parser always succeeds, even if it can only parse an empty string. You can solve that problem by replacing `manyChars` in the definition of `part` with `many1Chars`.

If you search for e.g. "applied to a parser that succeeds without consuming input" you'll find several discussions of similar errors on the internet, including one in FParse's user guide: http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/parsing-sequences.html#the-many-parser

*Update:*
Here's a straightforward parser definition that works:

```
let sepPart = skipNewline 
              >>? (skipMany1SatisfyL ((=) '-') "'-'" 
                    >>. (skipNewline <|> eof))

let part = many1CharsTill anyChar sepPart    
let parser = many part
```

Note that I'm using `>>?` in the definition of `sepPart` to allow this parser to backtrack to the beginning if a newline is not followed by a dash. Alternatively you could also use `attempt (skipNewline >>. ...)`, which would also backtrack for errors after the initial dash. The documentation for `many[Chars]Till p endp` states an equivalence with `many (notFollowedBy endp >>. p) .>> endp` that is not strictly true, because `many[Chars]Till` does not backtrack like `notFollowedBy`. I will clarify the documentation.

It's better for performance if you avoid backtracking using `many[Chars]Till` or `notFollowedBy` where possible. For example, you could also parse your chunks of lines as follows:

```
let id = manyMinMaxSatisfyL 2 2 isUpper "id (two capital letters)"

let line = id .>>. (pchar ' ' >>. restOfLine true)

let separator = many1SatisfyL ((=) '-') "dash separator"
                >>. (skipNewline <|> eof)

let chunk = many1 line     
let parser = sepEndBy1 chunk separator
```

Note that this implementation doesn't require the last chunk to be ended by a separator. If you want that, you could instead use:

```
let chunk = many line .>> separator
let parser = many chunk
```

If you want to allow empty chunks with the `sepEndBy` definition, you could use:

```
let chunk = many1 line <|> (notFollowedByEof >>% [])
let parser = sepEndBy1 chunk separator
```

Comment: This does suppress the error, however it does not return the correct result. If you look at what is returned by the first parse {test part s} you will see the result changes when manyChars is changed to many1Chars in the part parser.

Comment: I don't see the difference, except for `part` returning a string and `many part` returning a string in a list. Could you please be more specific and explain what output you're expecting? Your parser never skips the `sepPart`, so maybe you want something like `many (part .>> sepPart)`. If you want to match one or more dashes for the separator, you'll also have to use something like `skipMany1 (pstring "-")` or `skipMany1SatisfyL ((=) '-') "'-'"` in the definition of `sepPart`.

Comment: I edited the question to better describe the expected output. I appologise for not making it clearer to begin with.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please ask if you find anything unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I had to update the answer again, because the proposed simpler solution had a bug: there was one `many` too many.